# Parallel version of transform (or mutate) in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a slow function that I want to apply to each row in a data.frame. The computation is embarrassingly parallel.

I have 4 cores, but R's built in functions only uses one.

All I want to do is a parallel equivalent to:

```
data$c = slow.foo(data$a, data$b)
```

I can't find clear instructions on which library to use (overwhelmed by choice) and how to use it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `parallel` package is included with base R. Here's a quick example using `parApply` from that package:

```
library(parallel)

# Some dummy data
d <- data.frame(x1=runif(1000), x2=runif(1000))

# Create a cluster with 1 fewer cores than are available. Adjust as necessary
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)

# Just like regular apply, but rows get sent to the various processes
out <- parApply(cl, d, 1, function(x) x[1] - x[2])

stopCluster(cl)

# Same as x1 - x2?
identical(out, d$x1 - d$x2)

# [1] TRUE
```

You also have, e.g., `parSapply` and `parLapply` at your disposal.

Of course, for the example I've given, the vectorised operation `d$x1 - d$x2` is **much** faster. Think about whether your processes can be vectorised rather than performed row by row.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Your example works, but I can't get a named equivalent to work. I changed `x[1]-x[2]` to `x$x1-x$x2`. That yields the following error: 

     `Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  7 nodes produced errors; first error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Comment: @sharoz: This is because the rows are simplified to vectors (for which `$` subsetting is not an option). The same would occur for the non-parallel `apply(d, 1, function(x) x$x1 - x$x2)`. If you want to use names, you can do: `function(x) x['x1'] - x['x2']`.

Comment: Thanks again, but it's hitting problems with named variables. Per the original example, I defined `bar <- function(x) slow.foo(x['a'], x['b'])`. Then I ran `parApply(cl, d, 1, bar)` which can't find the symbol slow.foo (even though it's defined). Any ideas?

Comment: @sharoz: Other than the object that you pass to `parApply` (i.e., `d`), you need to send objects/functions to the cluster processes with `clusterExport`. Try: `clusterExport(cl, 'slow.foo')` prior to `parApply`. This character vector should also include names of any objects referred to within the body of `slow.foo` (other than those that are passed from `bar`). Be aware that if any of said objects are huge, you might run into memory problems by sending copies to all processes.